# IndexError: list index out of range in Django-Python application

Tags: python-3.x, django-views

I have a problem with a function which has an iteration for an array. Here is my function;

```
def create_new_product():
    tree = ET.parse('products.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()

    array = []

    appointments = root.getchildren()
    for appointment in appointments:
        appt_children = appointment.getchildren()

        array.clear()

        for appt_child in appt_children:
            temp = appt_child.text
            array.append(temp)

        new_product = Product(
                product_name = array[0],
                product_desc = array[1]
        )
        new_product.save()

    return new_product
```

When I call the function, it saves 2 products into database but gives an error on third one. This is the error;

```
    product_name = array[0],
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is also the xml file. I only copied the first 3 products from xml. There are almost 2700 products in the xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Products>
  <Product>
    <product_name>Example 1</product_name>
    <product_desc>EX101</product_desc>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <product_name>Example 2</product_name>
    <product_desc>EX102</product_desc>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <product_name>Example 3</product_name>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error because it already works for the first two products in the xml file.

Comment: can you post the xml file ?

Comment: I added the xml file @madjaoue

Comment: Could you try the code I posted and tell me if you get the same output as shown ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run a minimal version of your code on python 3 (I assume it's 3 since you use `array.clear()`):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def create_new_product():
    tree = ET.parse('./products.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()

    array = []

    appointments = root.getchildren()
    for appointment in appointments:
        appt_children = appointment.getchildren()
        array.clear()

        # skip this element and log a warning
        if len(appt_children) != 2:
          print ('Warning : skipping element since it has less children than 2')
          continue

        for appt_child in appt_children:
            temp = appt_child.text
            array.append(temp)

        _arg={
                'product_name' : array[0],
                'product_desc' : array[1]
        }
        print(_arg)

create_new_product()
```

Output :

```
{'product_name': 'Example 1', 'product_desc': 'EX101'}
{'product_name': 'Example 2', 'product_desc': 'EX102'}
Warning : skipping element since it has less children than 2
```

Edit : OP has found that the products contain sometime less children than expected. I added a check of the elements number.

Comment: I realized that the problem is coming from the xml file. I mean there are normally 27 fields for each product but I found that some of them have 25 fields. That is why I am getting the error. Now, it is ok. I will edit my question to show this error and then if you change your answer accordingly, I will accept it for the other users, so that they can understand why that happens. Than you for your answer.

Comment: I edited my post so that it warns when the number of children is different from the one you expect.

Answer (score 0):

List index out of range is only thrown when a place in an array is invalid, so product_name[0] doesn't actually exist. Maybe try posting your XML file and and we'll see if there's an error there.

Comment: I added the xml file